# Loop Through Table Data and Get the Data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, loops, attributes, each

I'm a total novice when it comes to jQuery and i'm really struggling :( i have an HTML table where there's image URLs and i want to click a button and these image URLs replace the images with the class ".pic"'s src attribute so it displays the new images for each but at the moment it's only grabbing the last results in the table and applying this url to all the src of the images on the page so they all become that 1 image

this is what the table looks like when a user uploads their CSV with the image URLs in this
[image]

they then press a generate button and it should replace the product images in this section
[image]

However this is what's happening when they press generate, it just takes the last image URL and uses that to replace src instead
[image]

Thank you so much for your help and patience with me on this, sorry if i am not clear enough!

here's the code:

```
var table = $("table.mytable");
table.find('tr').each(function() {
  var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
    imageName = $tds.eq(0).text();

  $('.pic').select().each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', '' + imageName);
    // this alert code will show me all the image urls one by one so i kno it is grabbing the data correctly, just not applying properly to the image source 
    //alert('' +imageName)'
  });

});
```

Comment: The triple-backticks shouldn't be on the same line as the code, they should be before and after.

Comment: You're setting the source of all `.pic` elements, not just the ones in the current row.

Comment: Can you provide the html code of the table?

Comment: You probably want `$(this).find(".pic")`. There's also no need for `.select()`.

Comment: Just `$(this).find(".pic").attr("src", imageName)`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for getting back to me! Unfortunatley, no luck so far :(

I've tried this and this grabs the first value now instead of the last and applies it to the img src but i want it to take each value and set each one uniquely to the images, i'm not sure if i'm explaining properly >.<

`var table = $("table.mytable");
    table.find('tr').each(function () {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
  imageName = $tds.eq(0).text();
  $(imageName).select().each(function() {
        $('.pic').attr('src', '' + imageName);
   });
 }); `